# Is it safe to set the tsconfig target to es6 if you don't care about old browsers?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, angular-library

In an Angular application, is it safe to set the `tsconfig.json` **compilerOptions.target** to `"es6"` (or the equivalent `"es2015"`) if you don't care about old browsers?

About this matter, in the [official Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#target) is written:

> By default, the target is es5, you can configure the target to es6 if you only want to deploy the application to es6 compatible browser. But if you configure the target to es6 in some old browser such as IE, Syntax Error will be thrown.

So assuming that I do want to deploy my application only to es6 compatible browsers ***ONLY***, should I just set the compile target to es6

Are there any other concerns I should be aware of?

For example, some Angular third-part libraries start not working and throw the notorious error:

> TypeError: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'

is it correct to assume that in these cases there is a bug in such third-part library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Definitely you can use es6 in your `tsconfig.json` Currently I am using `esnext` for my application from past 10 months as I am targeting only google chrome, I didn't find any issues arising because of that

Thanks! Happy Coding